# In Spring Kafka, do I need to add the @EnableKafka annotation to my application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I see some people adding @EnableKafka to their spring boot application and I was wondering why. I have a working spring boot kafka producer and consumer and I didn't use @EnableKafka. So, why do people need to add it explicitly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

That is because Spring boot provides an auto configuration for Kafka via `KafkaAutoConfiguration` class ([javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/kafka/KafkaAutoConfiguration.html)). When you use `@EnableAutoConfiguration` or `@SpringBootApplication`, Spring boot automatically configures Kafka for you.

You can test that by excluding the auto configuration by providing `@SpringBootApplication(exclude={KafkaAutoConfiguration.class})`, and Spring boot would not automatically configure Kafka for you.

If you don't use Spring boot, then you would have to use `@EnableKafka` to configure Kafka for your Spring app.

Answer (score 18):

Spring Boot auto-configures `@EnableKafka` if it detects spring-kafka on the class path.

It is therefore not needed again on a boot app; it is only needed if your Spring app is not a Boot app.